# Nvidia strange behaviour with hdmi

Tags: nvidia, hdmi, colors, displayport

I've spent half a day trying to figure why with HDMI2.0 cable colors on my monitor were wrong, and then I've played with `Color controls` in `Nvidia X server settings` and found out that the correct colors (or so they seems to be) can be obtained if you switch from `RBG/Full` to `YCbCr444/Limited` and back to `RBG/Limited`

My driver is `nvidia-378`

Comment: The problem was that my display was for some reason in TV mode. I've modified this is the display menu and now it works fine.